# Haskell - Implementing First Order Logic Expressions

Tags: haskell, ghci, first-order-logic

I am trying to implement FOL using Haskell. First order logic can be in the form of propositions connected together with connectives like And and Or. There is also quantifiers that have a limited scope in the expression.

What I did so far is:

import Data.List

```
data Prop 
    = Not Prop
    | Prop And Prop
    | Prop Or Prop
    | Prop Impl Prop
    | Prop Equiv Prop
    | ForAll String Prop
    | Exists String Prop
    deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
 Multiple declarations of ‘Prop’
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you are including quantifiers such as `ForAll` but you are not including any way to use quantified variables, i.e. predicates. I would add `Pred String [Term]` for predicates, where `data Term = Var String | App String [Term]`. You may also want to add equality as well.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought: the only way to get a value of type `Prop` right now is something crazy like `let a = Not b; b = Not a in ...` because this formula lacks *primitives*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you declare an algebraic data type, the right-hand side of the declaration is a "list" of possible constructors for this type. However, the constructors are just functions, meaning that they are used in prefix notation. You try to use the e.g. `And` constructor in an infix way which does not work.

The following code works well:

```hs
data Prop
    = Not Prop
    | And Prop Prop
    | Or Prop Prop
    | Impl Prop Prop
    | Equiv Prop Prop
    | ForAll String Prop
    | Exists String Prop
    deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

<strike>However, you can define functions mimicking the constructors, e.g. --</strike>

```hs
propAnd :: Prop -> Prop -> Prop
propAnd a b = And a b
```

and use these in an infix way using the backquotes: `` a `propAnd` b ``.
As suggested in the comments, this is not necessary as `And` can already be used in the infix way: `` a `And` b ``

Another option is to define the constructors themselves in an infix way:

```hs
data Prop
    = Not Prop
    | Prop `And` Prop
    | Prop `Or` Prop
    | Prop `Impl` Prop
    | Prop `Equiv` Prop
    | ForAll String Prop
    | Exists String Prop
    deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

and then both `` a `And` b `` and `And a b` work.

**Note**: your data type is infinite since all the constructors take one or more `Prop`s. I think you should also include some "atomic" constructors.

Comment: You are right about the atomic constrs so I tried adding them as such:
data Prop 
    = Not Prop
    | Prop `And` Prop | Obj `And` Obj | Prop `And` Obj | Obj `And` Prop
    | Prop `Or` Prop | Obj `Or` Obj | Prop `Or` Obj | Obj `Or` Prop
    | Prop `Impl` Prop | Obj `Impl` Obj | Prop `Impl` Obj | Obj `Impl` Prop
    | Prop `Equiv` Prop | Obj `Equiv` Obj | Prop `Equiv` Obj | Obj `Equiv` Prop
    | ForAll String Prop
    | Exists String Prop
    deriving (Eq, Ord)

data Obj
    = Var String
    | Pred String [Prop]
    deriving (Eq, Ord)

But it says I am making multiple declarations.

Comment: `propAnd` is actually redundant: even if the constructor `And` was declared in a non-infix way, the constructor can still be used infix using backticks as in ``a `And` b``.

Comment: @SalmaFG Now you are using `And` (and all the other constructors) multiple times. I don't know what is your idea of the design of your software so I don't know what should I suggest. In fact, I do know - post a new question with what are you struggling with.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to use `Prop` as a constructor name multiple times (the first word is always the constructor name). It seems that you want to use infix constructors for `And`, `Or` and others. In order to write them infix you need to put the constructor names in backticks.

```
data Prop
    = Not Prop
    | Prop `And` Prop
    ...
```

Comment: What exactly does this backtick mean? Does this make `And` a String?

Comment: @SalmaFG The backtick makes a normal name into an infix operator.

Answer (score 3):

You said

```
...
| Prop And Prop
...
```

What you need to say is

```
...
| And Prop Prop
...
```

(And similarly for all the others). The constructor name has to come *first*.